# Would a set of measure zero in a higher dimension be of measure zero in a lower dimension?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have confronted the following question while solving another problem. Specifically, in my case, I'm curious whether some set of measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^{k+n}$ be measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

In order to solve the below problem, I think I need this result.

[image]

The way I thought to solve this problem is, first given $D$, a set of measure zero in $R^k$, and a fixed $x_0\in A-D$, $D\times B$ is also of measure zero in $R^{k+n}$, and since $f$ is integrable in $Q$, the set of discontinuities, say $E$ is also of measure zero. Then clearly, $f(x_0,y)$, for all $y\in B$, is continuous except for some set of measure zero in $R^{k+n}$. Hence, the statement in the question is proven if I can show that, $f(x_0,y)$, for all $y\in B$, is continuous almost everywhere in $R^n$. But would this be true? And if so how can I prove it?

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or solutions.

Comment: If $S \subset \mathbb R^{k + n}$ has measure zero, then $S$ is not a subset of $\mathbb R^n$, so what would it mean for $S$ to "be measure zero in $\mathbb R^n$"?

Comment: You're right that is incorrect, I guess I mean the projection of $S$ onto $R^n$. For instance, in the case I'm talking about, $x_0$ is fixed, so $x_0\times B \cap E$, which can then be considered a subset of $R^n$. Would the projection of the set make sense?

Comment: The projection of a measure $0$ set unto a subspace does not have to be measure $0$. Take for example the line $y = x$ in $\Bbb R^2$. Definitely has $0$ area, but the projections are both all of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair That's right. But what about projection on a bounded set, or on a rectangle as in the above case?

Comment: Same example. Bounding the sets doesn't make the problem magically disappear.

Comment: Hmm..then is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: My suggestion: Consider the set $Q_\epsilon = \{(x, y) \in Q\;|\; \|x - x_0\| \le \epsilon\}$. This is a measurable subset of $Q$, so $\int_{Q_\epsilon} f$ also exists for all $\epsilon \ge 0$. You might be able to prove it from the $0$ case, but more likely you can use the non-zero $\epsilon$ values to limit the size of the set where integrability fails. My measure theory is rusty, though, so I am not sure.